# Increase the value of a column based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to increase the price of on the red pens in this example by 10%. Below is what I have have tried but it increases all the prices once it finds a match

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['red ballpoint pen','red felt tip pen', 'blue ballpoint pen','red eraser',],
                   'price':[1.50,2.00,1.50,.50]})
for x in df['item']:

if 'red' in x and 'pen' in x:
    df['price'] =  df['price']*.10 + df['price']
```

I can filter the item column and get the pens but I cannot figure out how to update the price in place without increasing the price on all items

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use np.where() to find where both pen and red exist

```
df['price'] = np.where((df['item'].str.contains('red')) & (df['item'].str.contains('pen')), df['price'] * 1.10, df['price'])
df
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `loc` and `str.contains`:

```
m = df['item'].str.contains('red') & df['item'].str.contains('pen')
df.loc[m, 'price'] *= 1.10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `pandas` to do this in a oneliner:

```
df.loc[df.item.str.contains('pen') & df.item.str.contains('red'), 'price'] *= 1.1
```